# How to not add arrows to links in my submenu in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am writing my own jQuery navigation submenu script.  When you hover over a link in the horizontal `nav` that has a `ul` tag, it makes that `ul` appear.  I have a bit of code that adds an arrow to the links in the horizontal `nav` if it has a submenu.  My problem is that it also adds the arrows to the links in the submenu.  This is not a big deal functionally, but it does look bad.

The odd part is that if I use `$(this).find('> a')` it screws up the appearance of the submenu. The submenu appears when I hover over the top-level link, but then disappears right away when the mouse leaves that link.  So I can basically see the entire submenu when the mouse is hovered over the top level link.  When the mouse leaves the top level link, the submenu disappears and I can't click on the submenu links.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsrf5jw3/). Change `$(this).find('a')` to `$(this).find('> a')` and you'll see what I mean.  Thanks for your time!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav ul li:has(ul)').each(function(){
        var listItem = $(this);
        $(this).find('> a').each(function(){
            var aTag = $(this);
            aTag.append('<img src="{img_url}/caret.png" width="8" height="8">');
            aTag.on('mouseover', function(){
                listItem.find('ul').each(function(){
                    $(this).css('display', 'block');
                });
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(){
                listItem.find('ul').each(function(){
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pull out the first `a` tag from your loop through .each

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('nav ul li:has(ul)').each(function () {
        var listItem = $(this);
            // first a tag as new var
            var aTagFirst = listItem.children('a');
            aTagFirst.append('<img src="{img_url}/caret.png" width="8" height="8">');

        $(this).find('a').each(function () {
            var aTag = $(this);
            aTag.on('mouseover', function () {
                listItem.find('ul').each(function () {
                    $(this).css('display', 'block');
                });
            })
                .on('mouseout', function () {
                listItem.find('ul').each(function () {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vwaup28o/)**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do it by CSS, I have removed events `mouseover`, `mouseout` and added this styles:

```
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

li:hover a {
    background: #66cc00;
}

li:hover li a {
    background: #333;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fsrf5jw3/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('nav ul li:has(ul)').each(function () {
        var listItem = $(this);
        $(this).find('> a,>ul').each(function () {
            var aTag = $(this);
            aTag.append('<img src="{img_url}/caret.png" width="8" height="8">');
            aTag.on('mouseover', function () {
                listItem.find('ul').each(function () {
                    $(this).css('display', 'block');
                });
            })
            .on('mouseout', function () {
                listItem.find('ul').each(function () {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here only update is:

```
$(this).find('> a,>ul')
```

Css:

only update is one:

```
nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #333;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height:55px;
}
```

Update in padding and add line-height.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fsrf5jw3/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add hover callbacks to your `li` element, not `a` element, so the code becomes:

```
var listItem = $(this);
listItem.find('> a').each(function(){
    var aTag = $(this);
    aTag.append('<img src="{img_url}/caret.png" width="8" height="8">');
});

listItem
    .on('mouseover', function(){
        listItem.find('ul').each(function(){
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
        });
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(){
        listItem.find('ul').each(function(){
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
```

Also, as `marsh` answer goes, it is more proper performance-wise to do such things with css, not javascript.